Why does the grep command select more than expected?
When i write below command, it selects "aapp". but it should be "aap". Because '*' means zero or more 'a'.'p' means one p.
$ echo "aapple" | grep  "a*p"

terminal screenshot
can somebody please explain the reason, why the grep not select as expected?

grep prints the entire line when any part of it matches the specified RE.  Thus any input line containing a p will be printed.

You may be looking for the --only-matching (-o) option. From the man page: "Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line."

What's the expected output?

I expect to see only 'aap' in red.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Grep is line oriented, so it reads lines from input, and prints the entire line when any part of it matches the specified RE. Thus any input line containing a p will be printed with a*p.
$ echo "aapple" | grep "a*p"
aapple
$ echo "nothing special" | grep "a*p"
nothing special

If you only want to print the part that matches the RE, you can use the -o option, but then it will print multiple lines if the RE matches in multiple non-overlapping places:
$ echo "aapple" | grep  -o "a*p"
aap
p

If you use the --color option, it will print these two parts of the line in red, giving what you see in your image.

What I want to ask is actually why aapp was chosen as red. Shouldn't it just be aap?

When used it  with 'o', it selects 2 line, the first line is aap, the 2nd line is only p

You're apparently using the --color option.  With that it prints all the matches in red.  This line has two matches -- aap and p so they both get colored.

You provided command works in this way. * mean it print if "a" is just right on next of "p".
But if "a" is not just concatenate with "p" on right side, it only print "P".
Terminal
